# Foot/head of stairs

Tags: expressions

I just want to confirm that I am right about these expressions.

The "foot of the stairs" is the bottom of the staircase, and the "head of the stairs" is the top, correct?

Are these expressions commonly used? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: They are correct, and not too likely to be not understood in the US.  "Top of the stairs" is probably more common, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Who in the world would not use and understand those? Those are the customary formulations: head and foot of the staircase. I begin to wonder whether you and I actually live in the same country after all. :)

Comment: As a Brit, the meaning of 'head of the stairs' is perfectly obvious, but we'd always use 'top'.

Comment: @tchrist: I've wondered the same thing myself.

Comment: @HotLicks As a Brit, I assume that "not too likely to be not understood" means "likely to be understood"?

Comment: @TrevorD - You get the gold star!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stairs I use '*foot*' often, but I usually say '*top*'.

Not familiar with '*head*' for stairs.  But I have learned, and say '*head*' (and *'foot'*) of the weir (man-made slope on a river).

Comment: As a lifetime resident mid-Atlantic US, this is all I've ever heard.